# Где ошибка в регулярном выражении поиска атрибутов в bbCode?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Сразу скажу, что с регулярными выражениями у меня не складывается общение :(

По этому поводу, прошу помощи.

Есть строка вида:

`... text text [text id="123" test="test"]text text text[/text] text text ... [text id="321" atribute="test"]text text text[/text]`

Нужно найти все подстроки находящиеся в `[]` т.е в данном случае `text id="123″ test="test"` и `text id="321″ atribute="test"`

Что я делаю:

```
preg_match_all('/[([^]]+)]/i',$str,$found);
```

Регулярку нашел [тут](http://site.softmaker.kz/php/primery-regulyarnyx-vyrazhenij-v-php.html). Но не работает.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Экранируйте квадратные скобки в регулярке --> `/\[([^\]]+)\]/i`

Comment: Да, и модификатор игнорирования регистра `i` в данной регулярке не нужен, так как кроме квадратных скобок у вас в ней ни чего нет.

Comment: @Visman Вы мне помогли! Ответьте и я выберу ваш ответ правильным! Спасибо большое

Comment: @Visman Может посоветуете хорошую литературу или видео материалы для изучения регулярных выражений?

Comment: @ЮрийКовалев https://regex101.com

Comment: @ЮрийКовалев http://www.books.ru/books/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-3-e-izdanie-592346/

Comment: А я всегда читаю статью на [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), если что-то забываю по регуляркам. Синтаксис един для всех платформ, главное помнить про необходимость экранирования в некоторых средах(например PHP)

Comment: @ЮрийКовалев, в конце [**описания метки «регулярные выражения»**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/info) литература для изучения указана.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$str = '... text text [text id="123" test="test"]text text text[/text] '.
       'text text ... [text id="321" atribute="test"]text text text[/text]';
preg_match_all('/\[(?=text)([^\]]+)\]/i', $str, $found);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($found[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '... text text [text id="123" test="test"]text text text[/text] text text ... [text id="321" atribute="test"]text text text[/text]';
// Ищем только открывающие тэги
preg_match_all('@
    \[ # Экранируем [, иначе это будет трактоваться как символьный класс
        (?!/) # Только если после скобки НЕТ знака /, т. е. закрывающие тэги не будут найдены
        ( # Запоминаем группу
            [^\]]+? # Берём все символы, кроме ] (именно символа ], а не конец символьного класса)
        )
    \] # Мой дед всегда говорил: сомневаешься - экранируй :)
    @x', $str, $match);
// Ищем все тэги
// preg_match_all('@\[([^\]]+)\]@', $str, $match);
var_dump($match[1]);
```

https://repl.it/CfCg/0

Answer (score 0):

```
/\[([^\/]+?)\]/g
```

g (global) - будет искать все вхождения регулярки в тексте

рекомендую использовать ресурс https://regex101.com/ для проверки регулярок

```
/\[([^\]]+)\]/i
```

эта регулярка не верна, она находит только первое вхождение, кроме того, она считает верным вхождение вида [/text]